# Does fog clean the air of fine dust

Tags: water, atmospheric-science, weather, humidity

When fog forms, the air is usually saturated with moisture. Thus, small droplets form and creates fog. Suspended fine dust can serve as condensation nuclei during the formation of fog.
So my question is: when fog forms overnight over a city, is the air cleaned of fine dust, as the dust particles are now trapped within the water droplets?

Comment: That could potentially be tested experimentally: weatherunderground for example has quite detailled weather data for any location (including visibilty and air humidity), while other databases provide data on the air pollution. One could compare the dips in air pollution with peaks in humidity (and a decrease in visibility). The air pollution should decrease after some time of higher humidity and lower visibility, if what you are suggesting is actually the case.

Comment: You would need the fog actually to remove the dust somehow I think.  If it just tuns back into water vapour, the dust is still there.

Answer (score 1):

only if the fog descends and then one of two things happen:
 1: it rains or
 2: the fog blows away

Answer (score 0):

Fog does  trap Particles in the air   That is why it’s not recommend  to drink fog water . It would be drinking dirty water  which is relatively harmless to plant and insect life.  And fine Mist  sprayers are used around construction site to trap air particles keep dirt from coming out
[image]